# Postgres 9.0 slow query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am evaluating postgres to migrate away from Oracle.  The following query runs too slow, also please find the explain plan:

```
explain analyze select DISTINCT EVENT.ID, 
   ORIGIN.ID AS RIGINID,EVENT.PREFERRED_ORIGIN_ID AS PREFERRED_ORIGIN, 
   EVENT.CONTRIBUTOR, ORIGIN.TIME, ORIGIN.LATITUDE, ORIGIN.LONGITUDE, 
   ORIGIN.DEPTH, ORIGIN.EVTYPE, ORIGIN.CATALOG, ORIGIN.AUTHOR OAUTHOR,
   ORIGIN.CONTRIBUTOR OCONTRIBUTOR, 
   MAGNITUDE.ID AS MAGID, MAGNITUDE.MAGNITUDE, MAGNITUDE.TYPE AS MAGTYPE
from event.event 
   left join event.origin on event.id = origin.eventid 
   left join event.magnitude on origin.id = event.magnitude.origin_id 
WHERE EXISTS(
    select origin_id from event.magnitude 
    where magnitude.magnitude>=7.2 
    and origin.id=origin_id) 
order by ORIGIN.TIME desc, MAGNITUDE.MAGNITUDE desc,
    EVENT.ID,EVENT.PREFERRED_ORIGIN_ID,ORIGIN.ID


"Unique  (cost=740549.86..741151.42 rows=15039 width=80) (actual time=17791.557..17799.092 rows=5517 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=740549.86..740587.45 rows=15039 width=80) (actual time=17791.556..17792.220 rows=5517 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: origin."time", event.magnitude.magnitude, event.id, event.preferred_origin_id, origin.id, event.contributor, origin.latitude, origin.longitude, origin.depth, origin.evtype, origin.catalog, origin.author, origin.contributor, event.magnitude.id, event.magnitude.type"
"        Sort Method:  quicksort  Memory: 968kB"
"        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=34642.50..739506.42 rows=15039 width=80) (actual time=6.927..17769.788 rows=5517 loops=1)"
"              ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=34642.50..723750.23 rows=14382 width=62) (actual time=6.912..17744.858 rows=2246 loops=1)"
"                    Hash Cond: (origin.id = event.magnitude.origin_id)"
"                    ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=0.00..641544.72 rows=6133105 width=62) (actual time=0.036..16221.008 rows=6133105 loops=1)"
"                          Merge Cond: (event.id = origin.eventid)"
"                          ->  Index Scan using event_key_index on event  (cost=0.00..163046.53 rows=3272228 width=12) (actual time=0.017..1243.616 rows=3276192 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Index Scan using origin_fk_index on origin  (cost=0.00..393653.81 rows=6133105 width=54) (actual time=0.013..3033.657 rows=6133105 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=34462.73..34462.73 rows=14382 width=4) (actual time=6.668..6.668 rows=3198 loops=1)"
"                          Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 113kB"
"                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on magnitude  (cost=324.65..34462.73 rows=14382 width=4) (actual time=1.682..5.414 rows=3198 loops=1)"
"                                Recheck Cond: (magnitude >= 7.2)"
"                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on mag_index  (cost=0.00..321.05 rows=14382 width=0) (actual time=1.331..1.331 rows=3198 loops=1)"
"                                      Index Cond: (magnitude >= 7.2)"
"              ->  Index Scan using mag_fkey_index on magnitude  (cost=0.00..1.06 rows=3 width=22) (actual time=0.007..0.009 rows=2 loops=2246)"
"                    Index Cond: (origin.id = event.magnitude.origin_id)"
"Total runtime: 17799.669 ms"
```

This query runs in Oracle in 1 second while takes 16 seconds in postgres, The difference tells me that I am doing something wrong somewhere.  This is a new installation on a local Mac machine with 12G of RAM.

I have:

```
effective_cache_size=4096MB   
shared_buffer=2048MB  
work_mem=100MB
```

Comment: +1 for posting the execution plan.

Comment: Are you sure the 1 second on Oracle wasn't due to query caching from running the query previously?

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove `DISTINCT` from your `SELECT` clause. It's redundant since you are selecting `PRIMARY KEY` columns anyway.
2. Change the `LEFT JOIN` into the `INNER JOIN`. As others mentioned, your `EXISTS` clause eliminates all possible `NULL` outputs generated by the `LEFT JOIN`.
3. Create two indexes:

   ```
   magnitude (magnitude, origin_id)
   magnitude (origin_id, magnitude)
   ```

   (each of them may be more efficient depending of how selective is your `magnitude >= 7.2` conditions)

```
SELECT  EVENT.ID, 
        ORIGIN.ID AS RIGINID,EVENT.PREFERRED_ORIGIN_ID AS PREFERRED_ORIGIN, 
        EVENT.CONTRIBUTOR, ORIGIN.TIME, ORIGIN.LATITUDE, ORIGIN.LONGITUDE, 
        ORIGIN.DEPTH, ORIGIN.EVTYPE, ORIGIN.CATALOG, ORIGIN.AUTHOR OAUTHOR,
        ORIGIN.CONTRIBUTOR OCONTRIBUTOR, 
        MAGNITUDE.ID AS MAGID, MAGNITUDE.MAGNITUDE, MAGNITUDE.TYPE AS MAGTYPE
FROM    event.event
JOIN    event.origin
ON      origin.eventid = event.id
JOIN    event.magnitude
ON      magnitude.origin_id = origin.id
WHERE   origin.id IN
        (
        SELECT  origin_id
        FROM    magnitude
        WHERE   magnitude >= 7.2
        )
ORDER BY
        ORIGIN.TIME desc, MAGNITUDE.MAGNITUDE desc,
        EVENT.ID,EVENT.PREFERRED_ORIGIN_ID,ORIGIN.ID
```

A sample query to check:

```
WITH    event (id) AS
        (
        VALUES
                (1)
        ),
        origin (id, eventid) AS
        (
        VALUES
                (1, 1),
                (2, 1)
        ),
        magnitude (id, origin_id, magnitude) AS
        (
        VALUES
                (1, 1, 4),
                (2, 1, 8),
                (3, 3, 6)
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    event
LEFT JOIN
        origin
ON      origin.eventid = event.id
LEFT JOIN
        magnitude
ON      magnitude.origin_id = origin.id
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  origin_id
        FROM    magnitude 
        WHERE   magnitude.magnitude >= 7.2 
                AND origin.id = origin_id
        )
```

Both magnitudes, `4` and `8`, are returned for `origin 1`.

Comment: You can push the "magnitude >= 7.2" condition the JOIN condition as well, to get rid of the subselect.

Comment: @Frank: this will change the semantics on the query. If an origin has two magnitudes, say, `4` and `8`, both need to be selected. Pushing the condition into the join would filter the `4` one out.

Comment: Apologies -- I understand now.  Comments were made Before Coffee (tm)

Comment: @OMGPonies: next time just upvote and see the other unbelievers blush! :)

Answer (score 0):

As has already been answered in at least one of the other forums you posted this question in, change the "   left join event.origin on event.id = origin.eventid " part to be an inner join, since your EXISTS query further down restricts it to that anyway.

Comment: Additional filter criteria does not change OUTER to INNER JOINs, it just restricts the data returned.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: a NULL and a match are two different things. And a INNER JOIN will result in a different query plan.

Comment: @Frank Heikens: An INNER JOIN doesn't produce NULLs in missing output.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: That's correct, that's also my point: EXISTS won't produce NULL's either. It's the INNER JOIN you're looking for, not a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @Frank Heikens: The EXISTS in the example is going to filter out rows, there's still going to be NULL references.  You're advocating a different result set, which is what you downvoted my answer for doing.

Answer (score 0):

There are useful links for learning how to interpret your own execution plan at the [PostgreSQL wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Using_EXPLAIN).

Answer (score 0):

According to the plan:

> Sort  (cost=740549.86..740587.45 rows=15039 width=80) (actual time=17791.55 ...

The sort operator was the main bottleneck. Try removing the `order by` statement?

Comment: This should be submitted as a comment when you have enough [reputation points](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). Until you have enough reputation, you can [post questions] or submit answers with more of an explanation.